# Amazon CloudFront not working with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops, amazon-cloudfront

I am a AWS beginner. I have my website hosted on beanstalk. Endpoint of beanstalk is added to CNAME record for my personal domain so that I can access it using personal domain and https. I am able to access it (added name www for endpoint of beanstalk in CNAME). I wanted to integrate CloudFront with my website so I created distribution, set origin as [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (personal domain). And also set alternate domain name as same domain and attached certificates for my domain. After creation of distribution, got the CloudFront domain (123455xx.cloudfront.net). On opening this CloudFront domain, website loaded successfully. But if now I open website from my domain, and after inspecting element, there is no ‘via’ CloudFront in console headers. Help.        For clarification I have 1 CNAME record in Godaddy with name as www and value as endpoint of beanstalk

I tried changing the origin from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (personal domain) to end point of beanstalk and then added alternate domain in cloudfront distribution as my personal domain with certificates attached and then edited the cname record with name www and value as the distribution domain (12345xx.cloudfront.net). Then if I accessed my personal domain, it shows error 502 and logs shows permission denied

Thanks

Comment: Error 502 probably means that you EB is incorrectly setup.

Comment: thanks  for the reply. how to troubleshoot ?

Comment: Everything  you did in your 2nd paragraph is correct. Those are the correct steps to send traffic intended for your domain to CloudFront, and have CloudFront use your Elastic Beanstalk application as the origin. Please see this list of possible reasons for the 502 error: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html Did you perhaps configure your origin as HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Comment: @MarkB is there any way we can see if cloudfront was used or not. I tried some new thing but ehen i access the url, application loads up. Just need to verify if cloudfront routed the request to beanstalk.

Comment: @MohammadAyan - did you ever figure out the problem or do you still have this issue? You can use [standard CloudFront logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html) to pipe access logs to S3, which you can further parse and [send to CloudWatch for easier viewing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html)